# Handling with an Error caused by using GARCH(1,1) in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need help for handling with an error in matlab caused with the function

```
estimate(garch(1,1),x')
```

from the Economic Toolbox.
My exercise is to predict values for value-at-risks by using garch(1,1)-models for discrete returns $R$ of share prices $data$

```
    for i=1:length(data-1)
         R(i-1)=data(i)/data(i-1)-1;
     end
```

of various public companys from 2004 till 2016. 
Therefore I am using for example 250 discrete returns from the past to predict a value for the actual value-at-risk:

```
  for j=1:length(R)-n
    daten=R(j:(n+j-1));
    x=daten-mean(daten)*ones(1,n);
    fit  = estimate(garch(1,1),x');
    estParams = ['Constant',cell2mat(fit.GARCH), cell2mat(fit.ARCH)];
    alpha0(j)=estParams(1);
    alpha1(j)=estParams(2);
    beta1(j)=estParams(3);

end
```

n equals to 250 here.
The problem is, that I am always getting this error after certain runs of my if-loop, because the data doesnt fit to a garch(1,1)-model:

```
Error using VaR_garch (line 21)
Estimated GARCH model is invalid.

Caused by:
   Error using garch/validateModel (line 791)
   Non-zero degree P requires a non-zero degree Q.
```

and the corresponding lines of garch.m are

```
 if (Mdl.P > 0) && (Mdl.Q == 0)
  error(message('econ:garch:validateModel:InvalidModelDegrees'))
end
```

So I need to use

```
       estimate(garch(1,0),x')
```

in my if-loop, when I get my error.
How can I deal with this error, so matlab is going on with estimation the parameters in my if-loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you probably know this but ask on MATLab on https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/index?s_tid=mlc_an_ask I think you'll most likely get a quicker response!

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think there are also experts on this site, who are able to help me, but I will post my question on your posted site.

Comment: Both work, just worth a shot.